# How to use model structure from ZF2 Blog tutorial in a real world application?

Tags: orm, model, zend-framework2, data-access-layer, datamapper

I'm currently developing a ZF2 application and want to implement it pretty similar to the [ZF2 example Blog application](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/in-depth-guide/first-module.html). Probably in the future the DAL will be replaced by Doctrine, but in the first version the model should work like in the Blog application: `Service + Mapper + Data Objects`.

In the Blog application the method `ZendDbSqlMapper#save(...)` gets (like every other public method of a `Mapper`) an Data Object as argument, extracts it, and writes then the data to the database. But my real world case is a bit more complex and I don't (but want to) understand, whether the approach is still applicable to it and how.

The application should primarily deal with (saving and retrieving of) requests / orders of some technical services. (In the next step they are manually processed by an employee and implemented.) So, the common case will be the saving (updating/creating) of an `Order`.

The physical model looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the `Order` has some dependencies, that also have dependencies etc. On creating an `Order`I have to create a `LogicalConnection` first. For a `LogicalConnection`an (abstract) `PhysicalConnection`and a concrete physical connection variant like `PhysicalConnectionX` are needed. (It implements the [Class Table Inheritance](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html).) Furthermore a `LogicalConnection`needs a new `Customer` (to simplify: every time a new customer for a new order) and an `Endpoint` with a concrete endpoint variant like `EndpointA` (also a CTI implementation). The tables on the left side of the data model are just basic data, that should/can not be changed. (Of course the updating is even a bit more complicated, since I have to check for every related object, if it already exists, to avoid e.g. creating of multiple customers for the same endpoint.)

My first idea was to implement it like this:

- transform the input, the model gets from the form (I don't use `Zend\Collection`, because my for is structured completely diffreren that my objects and the database);
- hydrate the `Order` object for it (recursive hydration is already implemented);
- create a `Mapper` for every object type;
- and let every `Mapper#save(...)`

  - call the `save(...)`on the mappers of the object it depends on;
  - and then care only for its object.

Pseudocode:

```
MyDataObjectA {
    $id;
    $myObjectB;
}

MyDataObjectB {
    $id;
}

MapperA {
    save($dataObjectA) {
        saving $dataObjectA
        calling MapperA#save($dataObjectA->getObjectB() )
    }
}

MapperB {
    save($dataObjectB) {
        saving $dataObjectB
    }
}
```

It's a lot of code and every case has to be handled manually. (And I'm not sure, but maybe I can have some problems with context dependent saving, since this approach doesn't concider the context.) However -- I don't believe, it's a recommended solution.

Well, it might smack of an ORM. But what's about the model structure from the ZF2 Blog tutorial? Is it applicable for such a case? Or is it only useful for very simple structures and nearly never for a real world application? (Then I would ask -- do we really need this tutorial, if it shows an approach, that nearly never can be used in a real application?) Or maybe I just understand something wrong and there is a better (efficient, elegant etc.) approach?